# MySQL easy question CURDATE()

Tags: datetime, mysql

I want to compare two results
one is stored in the first query, and the other is exactly the same as the first, but i want only to recieve data < today

```
    "SELECT  s.GSP_nom as nom, timestamp, COUNT(s.GSP_nom) as nb_votes, AVG(v.vote+v.prix+v.serviceClient+v.interface+v.interface+v.services)/6 as moy
   FROM votes_serveur AS v
   INNER JOIN serveur AS s ON v.idServ = s.idServ
    WHERE s.valide = 1
   AND v.date < CURDATE()
   GROUP BY s.GSP_nom 
            HAVING nb_votes > 9 
            ORDER BY moy DESC LIMIT 0,15";
```

is that correct ? 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY`, not `ROUP BY`
`v.date < CURDATE()` looks o.k.

Comment: @Tristan what is the question anyway? what is this first query and where is another?

Comment: what ? i'm not sure i understand well, my question was about curdate and you answered it. Thank you